# The global issue in mysql_fetch_array and mysql_num_rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

First i know that mysql_num_rows and mysql_fetch_array will be removed in the future 
but i need to use it for short period . 
and we all know that mysql_num_rows () expects parameter 1 is a global issue but even this moment i cant find the solution for this problem i checked out more than 100 scripts and still not have the answer .

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * from user WHERE email='$loginEmail'");
$row=mysql_num_rows ($sql);
if ($row!=0)
{
while ($array=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{Do this ...... CODE}
}
```

please help !

Comment: echo `mysql_error(); die();` and see what u get

Comment: Are you sure that the connection has already been opened? As Abhik said, try `echo mysql_error();`

Comment: i did it and the error was "sql syntax error" but as you see there's no mistakes in sql syntax

Comment: when i write mysql_error .. blank page result i have

Comment: Please tell us the output of `var_dump ($sql);`

Comment: `email='" . mysql_real_escape_string($loginEmail) . "'"`

Comment: the out put of var_dump($sql); is : resource(5) of type (mysql result)

Comment: Deadooshka i already using mysql_real_escape_string in the variable pluse i tried this way '"."'

Comment: Sorry: please put your SQL statement in a variable and give us the content of this variable too.

Comment: output for sql = string(67) "SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE email= 'mnmn_beb@yahoo.com'

Answer (score 0):

The word `user` is a reserved word in MySQL, if I recall correctly. About 99%  Sure it is.

So try enclosing your query in backticks.

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * from `user` WHERE `email`='$loginEmail'");
```

Comment: No, user is no reserved word in the sql dialect of MySQL, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: problem is still going on and user in example above just to explain i do not use it as table name :)